# javascript on onclick="return func();" stop working after first element by id

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

```
<button onclick="return validateEdit();" class="btn btn-primary submit-btn">Submit</button>

function validateEdit() {
  var name = document.getElementById("sftName").value;
  aler("name")
  var startTime = document.getElementById("startTimeEdit").value;
  aler("start time")
}
```

The function execute first alert and don't show second aler.I am using also:

```
$('#edit_shift').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var anchor = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
  var id = anchor.data('whatever')
  var from = anchor.data('fromtime')
  var modal = $(this)
  $("#sftName").attr("value", name);
  $("#startTimeEdit").attr("value", from);
```

In the another form is working fine.

Edit: start time  with value and without value is not working in both cases.

I am full zero at javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some typo error. Make sure its **alert** in your code and not **aler**. Also html content you posted having only button, whereas you are trying to fetch two elements with id **sftName** and **startTimeEdit**, make sure those elements are there in your code.
For better understanding can you recreate above issue on codepen.

Comment: You were right, it was having typo error in the alerts and one in the ID's of the elements.